# Extracting multiple variables from a changing string in bash

Tags: python, string, perl, date, datetime

I have multiple strings like that in a file, one per line:

```
[random string] was [failed/passed] 1y 2mo 3d 1h 51m 2s ago [some string]
```

Now what I want to do is extract the duration in 6 variables (years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds) to calculate a date with the "date" function. 
I would also like to get the pass/fail in a variable (eg O/1).

I have encountered 3 problems:

- I have trouble reading every line in a file containing those strings (for loop doesn't work very well...maybe a while would work better)
- If I managed to read a string, I've tried parsing it with cut, but I don't know how to get rid of the letters (y,mo,h...) and keep only the numbers.
- The duration format is variable; it can be 1mo 2h 3s when less than a year, or  1y 3d 58m 3s, or 3h 5s... etc. And I don't know how to deal with that variability. I'm guessing the command would have to check the letter and assign in function of that, and assign 0 to the non present ones.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `perl` code that I think will work for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $string = <STDIN>;
chomp $userword; # Get rid of newline character at the end
@arr = $string =~ /(passed|failed).+?([\d]+[yY].)?([\d]+(?:mo|MO).)?([\d]+[dD].)?([\d]+[hH].)?([\d]+[mM].)?([\d]+[sS])/g;
$arr_len = scalar @arr;
print "Result: $arr[0]\n";
for($i=1;$i<=$arr_len;$i=$i+1){
    $arr[$i]=~/(\d+)([A-Za-z]*)/g;
    if ( $2 eq "y" | $2 eq "Y" ) {
        print "Year is $1\n";
    } elsif ( $2 eq "mo" | $2 eq "MO") {
        print "Month is $1\n";
    } elsif ( $2 eq "d" | $2 eq "D") {
        print "Day is $1\n";
    } elsif ( $2 eq "h" | $2 eq "H") {
        print "Hour is $1\n";
    } elsif ( $2 eq "m" | $2 eq "M") {
        print "Minute is $1\n";
    } elsif ( $2 eq "s" | $2 eq "S" ) {
        print "Second is $1\n";
    }
}
```

I tried three different input and those are:

```
[random string] was failed 1y 2mo 3d 1h 51m 2s ago [some string]

[random string] was passed 2mo 3d 1h 51m 2s ago [some string]

asd  sd asdg s passed 1y 2mo 3d 1h 2s

[random string] was failed 1y 4d 5h 3m 2s ago [some string]
```

Output for all the three are shown accordingly:

```
Result: failed
Year is 1
Month is 2
Day is 3
Hour is 1
Minute is 51
Second is 2

Result: passed
Month is 2
Day is 3
Hour is 1
Minute is 51
Second is 2


Result: passed
Year is 1
Month is 2
Day is 3
Hour is 1
Second is 2


Result: failed
Year is 1
Day is 4
Hour is 5
Minute is 3
Second is 2
```

Here are few things:

1. I have not used `switch` because it might give an error saying `Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Switch module)`
2. I have tried my best to simplify the regex as far as possible, so if anyone can suggest a better regex to select please comment.
3. Also this is the first time that I have tried programming in `perl`. If anyone finds a way to improve the code, please suggest me. I would be highly grateful.

Comment: thank you for your answer! unfortunately, this doesn't work when the duration is, for example, 1y 4d 5h 3m 2s... Also, do you know how to get the fail/pass result?

Comment: @libussa, the code does work properly for the duration `1y 4d 5h 3m 2s`. Just have a look at the running code at the link I provided in my first comment. Also, I have updated it to get the result.